# How to block outgoing connections from process/user on FreeBSD?

Tags: networking, security, freebsd

My server executes third party software which processes user submitted files. I want to block outgoing connections from my process. How can I do it in FreeBSD?

Comment: I tried using Java's -DsocksProxyHost and -DsocksProxyPort system properties to redirect traffic to unexisting proxy server. It worked on Linux but not on FreeBSD. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for a [jail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD_jail). This is a restrictive environment in which processes have limited access to files, networks and system settings. The [handbook](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/jails.html) explains how to set up a jail. You'll want to block the jail from networking altogether with the `ipv4=disable ipv6=disable` parameters to [`jail`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=jail&sektion=8), or at least restrict connectivity to a few addresses with something like `ipv4.addr=127.0.0.1,192.168.42.17`.

Answer (score 1):

You could run this process under separate account and block traffic by UID, see 
[ipfw man page](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ipfw&sektion=8) for `uid` option.